# Time Complexity of Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

The worst case for calculating GCD of two numbers 'x' and 'y' by Euclidean Algorithm occurs when 'x' and 'y' are consecutive fibonacci numbers.
Suppose 'x' and 'y' are (n)th and (n-1)th terms of the Fibonacci sequence. Then the call to the function GCD(x,y) involves further (n-3) recursive calls each operation running in O(1) time.
So can we say that the running time of this algorithm is O(n) ?

Comment: No. Please extensively use Google before asking. https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Euclidean_algorithm#Algorithmic_efficiency

Answer (score 0):

No, the worst-case scenario of the runtime is *O(h)*, where *h* is the number of digits in your number *y*, where *y* is the smaller number.

This can be proven by induction.